# rake db: setup, TypeError: unable to resolve type 'size_t'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvNTQ.png) The ruby version i am using is 2.6.6 and am running this on M1 macbook with mac os 11.3.1.
i want set up mysql db but when i run the code it throws and error.

```
 rake db:setup
rake aborted!
TypeError: unable to resolve type 'size_t'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gem pristine ffi sassc
bundle update ffi
```